# php - How to maintain imap resource (returned by imap_open) throughout multiple requests?

Tags: php, imap

I want to maintain connection between php app and imap server throughout multiple requests within php app.
But the problem is that I can't figure how to put imap resource in singleton. Every time new request is issued static vars get erased and imap resource cannot be serialized.

Comment: You are talking about a `persistent connection`. That has nothing to do with a `singleton`.

Comment: Depends on your setup (which you did not mention...). If it is a standard setup, like php running as a module inside an apache prefork SAPI then you cannot. The requests are served by different processes.

Answer (score 2):

In short: you cannot.

What you are looking for is called `persistent connection`, but there is no way to open persistent connection to IMAP in PHP.

serialize() will not help you here, since `imap_open` returns "resource", and resources cannot be serialized.